# Unable to play mp4 files in the background

Tags: swift, avkit

I'm getting a strange error while trying to play background audio

I have done the following:

Capabilities ✅

Frameworks ✅

My code:

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var  playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
        print("Playback OK")
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        addPlayerNotifications()
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("Session is Active")

    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

`addPlayerNotifications()`:

```
func addPlayerNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidPlayToEnd), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}
```

However, this is a tabbar application when switching to the appropriate section i get a crash with this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.) on this line: `fatalError(error.localizedDescription)`

[image: IMG]

Even more strange,

This code works on:

Simulator ✅

Physical iPhone X (iOS 12.4.1) ❌

On another Xcode Project without Tabbar ✅

It's a simple tabbar with 2 view controllers. I really don't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest calling this fucntion with `isOn = false` when going in background and `true` when coming from foreground. This will turn off the track media but keep the sound.

```
func setPlayerMediaCharacteristic(isOn: Bool) {
    guard let currentPlayerItem = playerViewController.player?.currentItem else { return }

    for track in currentPlayerItem.tracks where track.assetTrack.hasMediaCharacteristic(.visual) {
        track.isEnabled = isOn
    }
}
```